# Permissions to a document library

Tags: document-library, permissions, groups

So I'm not sure how to do permissions or best practice for my situation.  So I work for a real estate company and when they buy a property they have documents for each stage of the project.  Stages are as follows: `Due Diligence -> Purchasing -> Management` 
Some people will only need access to the due diligence and some just need access to purchasing, and others to only management.  So reading up on this it looks like I might go the way of making three different document libraries, and then basing permission on those libraries, however documents will have to be moved from one library to the next as it progresses through the property purchase stage. Is there a way to base permission off metadata tags or content type on the documents, and just use one document library?

Answer (score 1):

I would just make one document library with three folders, uninherit those folders to make unique permissions, and then create a workflow that takes the document and moves it to a different folder. You can create a view that looks at all documents and the folder it's in.

Comment: My fear with folders is that if they make folders, they will not use any of the tagging.  I know its policy and user training.  Thank you for the response, curious to see what others think how to do this.  Also we will eventually have numerous properties, and will need to expand this out.

Comment: Have different views and different forms for the respective stages of the document. You can have three links that say "Upload Due Diligence" "Upload Purchasing" and "Upload Management" with three separate custom forms created in sharepoint designer that hones the fields you care about for each category.